# _ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));

Tags: c++, pointers, file-io

I'm working on an assignment that requires me to read data from a text file and store it into different arrays. The first for loop works perfectly fine but the 2nd for loop causes the error. The console output is correct but it won't let me continue with my program. What could be causing this?

```
void ReadFile(){
int totalVideos, cnt, i, custCnt, tempID;
cnt = 0;
custCnt = 0;
i = 0;
Video video[5];
Customer customer[10];
stringstream ss;
ifstream inStream;
inStream.open("Programming Assignment 4 Data.txt");

while(!inStream.eof()){
    string next;
    getline(inStream, next);
    ss<<next;
    ss>>totalVideos;
    for(totalVideos; totalVideos > 0; totalVideos--){
        int copies;
        getline(inStream, next);
        if(next.empty()){
            getline(inStream, next);
        }
        video[cnt].title = next;
        getline(inStream, next);
        video[cnt].star1 = next;
        getline(inStream, next);
        video[cnt].star2 = next;
        getline(inStream, next);
        video[cnt].producer = next;
        getline(inStream, next);
        video[cnt].director = next;
        getline(inStream, next);
        video[cnt].company = next;
        inStream>>copies;
        video[cnt].copies = copies;
        cout<<video[cnt].title<<endl;
        cout<<video[cnt].star1<<endl;
        cout<<video[cnt].star2<<endl;
        cout<<video[cnt].producer<<endl;
        cout<<video[cnt].director<<endl;
        cout<<video[cnt].company<<endl;
        cout<<video[cnt].copies<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        cnt++;
    }
    for(i; i < 4; i++){
        getline(inStream, next, ',');
        customer[i].firstName = next;
        getline(inStream, next, ',');
        customer[i].lastName = next;
        inStream>>tempID;
        customer[i].id = tempID;
        cout<<customer[i].firstName<<" "<<customer[i].lastName<<" "<<customer[i].id<<endl;
        custCnt++;
    }
}
```

}

EDIT: I've changed my main to contain only the following code and it still throws the error??

```
ifstream inStream;
inStream.open("Programming Assignment 4 Data.txt");

while(!inStream.eof()){
    string next = "";
    inStream>>next;
    cout<<next<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Difficult to say for certain without the whole code and input data. I suspect it's a buffer overflow in `video`, since it is rather short, you don't test if `cnt` is in range, and you process the last line of `inStream` twice (the eof condition is only set when a read operation fails because it encounters the end of the file, so you have to check for end-of-file after `getline`).

Comment: I'm assuming it's too late for this to be of use, but given your edit I think the error is outside of the ReadFile function you've listed here. Something earlier in your program is corrupting the heap, and the code here happens to be the first thing that breaks because of it.